# AN - Change Color and Text on Empty Location

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

**Let say I have a grid 3 x 3 of mesh plane objects and when I move an Empty object into center of the first Plane (upper-left), the blue color changes to pink and Text object (on side) changes number to "4".**

Note: The numbers shown on each plane will not be displayed in the animation. I only put them there to show you in which order the planes will change and how it corresponds with the numbering on the right.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do separated into steps:

**First**

I want to make the planes come from outside of screen view to a designated grid position (in ascendant order-see screen). Like 4, 5, 6 one by one and then continue 7, 8, 9 and so on; but with this current node tree (Directional) it all comes as a row at once instead of individually.

[image]

**Second**

I want to control the color of each individual plane by the position of another object. Like the Empty object in the plane location that'll change color from blue to pink.

**Third**

I have the text object next to the planes that I want to let display a specific number from text editor list (or in a specific range such as 4-12). That'll be controlled by the same object that controls the color of the plane. Ideally something like empty object hovering over the plane.

Thank you for help.
I really try to get in, but it seems it takes ages to dive into this system.

Answer (score 2):

### First Question

You can use the Delay Falloff node to do the animation after sorting them by name, making sure that our objects are named by their number.

[image: Node Tree 1]

### Second Question

What you need to do is check the max 1D distance (distance between components of vectors) to see if the empty is located inside the square or not, so a node tree like this works:

[image: Node Tree 2]

### Third Question

In the same loop, you add a text input and reassign it to the object name **if** and only if the boolean we computed before was true, so a node tree like this works:

[image: Node Tree 3]

I didn't describe each in details because you seem like you know AN. However, if you want them in details, please ask.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man :) From the tree I see you use group of objects. There is a way to use AN to generate the grid or use one object and let AN separate faces (that I saw somewhere), so is it problem to controle order later? I have like 100 planes in a grid, so it can be a problem to change size distance or shape of each segment later. On other hand this system I can handle :) "Sort list" expression accepted only numbers right? So I will check some batch-remane addon for that. And if I understood you right, name of object is used for text object too.

Comment: @vklidu If you want to use the Distribute Matrix node to generate the locations of the grid, you can sort the matrices instead of the objects. See this answer to know how:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92069/animation-node-grid-animation

Comment: @vklidu Sort List node can sort texts as well, alphabetically I think.

Comment: First - works. Second - I'm stack in the Loop node. What parameter type to choose for "Empty Location" and "Length"? Since you renamed it to better understand the purpose I'm out what to choose from parameter list. For Colors (Yes/No) parameter I took "Color", right? Third - what is the node "Reassign Loop Parameter" that I don't know how to create?

Comment: @vklidu Empty Location is a vector and Length is a float. In the advanced node settings of the loop input node, you will find a list of inputs with "Add Reassign" next to the "text" input. That's how you add the reassign node. To show the text as output check "output" from the same place.